# Apache smtp mail log

Tags: php, apache, email

Does apache save smtp mail logs (body)? I found the log file but I can only find the headers. Altough there is a Message-ID field. Is there any way I can find the body of the mail?

Comment: Apache isn't an SMTP server. It doesn't do SMTP at all. (Well, not without a lot of serious hacking).